# fonconfig fails, apt-get wont install programs

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dpkg, fonts

from `less /var/log/fontconfig.log`:
fc-cache: symbol lookup error: fc-cache: undefined symbol: FcDirCacheCreateUUID

apt-get and dpkg both fail to install apps and upgrades.I have tried `sudo dpkg -a --configure` and `sudo apt-get -f install`  neither have fixed the issue.

what else can I try? because of the fontconfig issue, things like mate-panel and various desktop apps fail to load. This also means Ill be implementing any solutions via the command line. I have also tried purging and reinstalling fontconfig, but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete output you get when trying to use e.g. apt-get to install some program.

Comment: Eh i solved it on my own, I purged some faulty nvidiea repos, and took care of the dependency issues I was having, after that, the errors stopped.